# I have no XAML intellisense in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

For some reason of late I have no intellisense in my XAML code for Visual Studio 2012.  Is this a bug or a feature. Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, no intellisense for xaml, and installing 'Visual Studio 2012 update 2' fixed it for me:
[Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912)

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it for me too. I didn't have Update 2 at the time of this posting.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And when I went on msdn website, I was able to download and install "update 4" for visual studio 2012, and it fixed the problem directly.

By the way, before installing I had this version of Visual studio 2012 :

VS 2012 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

This page gave me a hint that my version of VS2012 might be the cause of my problems.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7239

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I was using the Magellan Framework which was  trying to register controls under the presentation namespace URI. They did this so that you would have to use an XML prefix on there controls. This causes a problem with the Visual Studio 2012 XAML editor.

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Magellan")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Magellan.Abstractions")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Magellan.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Magellan.Views")]
```

I removed this from the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file of Magellan and it seems to have worked. I'll check this answer if the problem doesn't resurface.